# How can I stop Excel and Word hanging when trying to open documents in Protected View

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have recently started encountering a problem with my Office 2016 installation on Windows 10 where any attempt to open Word or Excel documents in Protected View cause the application to hang indefinitely before the document is opened.

This happens with documents which I have received by e-mail or downloaded from the Internet.

I can copy these files to a folder and 'Unblock' them by editing the properties, or (as many, many other websites suggest) I could disable Protected View altogether.

However - Protected View is obviously there for a reason, so I'd rather resolve the problem than simply turn off the protection!

Comment: Try to [Disable hardware graphics acceleration](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/excel-2016-stuck-on-opening-in-protected-view/). If this doesn't help, does the hang happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Safe mode and disabling graphics hardware acceleration does not help.

Comment: The conclusion is then that this isn't caused by some installed product. Have you tried to repair Office via *Control Panel > Programs and Features*?

Comment: @harrymc  Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately "Online Repair" did not solve the problem. At the moment I have disabled the Excel "Protected View", but I am not happy with this solution because it is not secure. I am still looking for a solution to this problem. Also, please put my nickname in the message as I am not the author of this issue and I do not get notifications.

Comment: @ComradeChe: Knowing whom to address is a problem in such a case. Try: Open a Protected View file as Administrator, meaning run Word or Excel as Administrator and open the file. Does it hang? If it doesn't hang, close the program and try to open the document again in normal mode.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but running Excel as an administrator does not solve the problem.

Comment: @ComradeChe: It still hangs as administrator?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, it is.

Comment: @ComradeChe: General troubleshooting: Do the first two points in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632505/8672).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to using a docking station (Targus ACP71EU) where the driver from [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/downloads.php) was the culprit.

Temporary work-around to fix the issue: In any Office application go to File > Options > Advanced > Display and check "Disable hardware graphics acceleration".

According to [DisplayLink's support forum](http://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/10494033-problem-with-new-version-7-9m3-office-protected) and my experience the problem should was solved in version 7.9M4 of the software.

Comment: I uninstalled DisplayLink and stopped having problems with Protected View. DIsplayLink has a new driver available now that should work, but I haven't tried it because I don't use it anymore.

Comment: This does **not** solve the problem: 1) Updating to `DisplayLink Graphics Version 10.1.2762.0` 2) Disabling `hardware graphics acceleration` 3) Uninstalling   `DisplayLink Graphics`. MS Office 2016.