# System \ ntoskrnl.exe \ RtlIoDecodeMemIoResource consuming 3-4% CPU constantly: why and how to avoid it?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, high-cpu-usage

My Laptop is using >= 10-15% CPU constantly when idle, specifically System >= 3-4% CPU, of which most comes from

`ntoskrnl.exe` `RtlIoDecodeMemIoResource`: 3-4% CPU at least at any time.

From what I read, this is not normal.

What can be sources of this, and are there solutions?

My Laptop: Win 10 64bit, i7, 16 GB RAM, SSD, Model: Lenovo X1.

P.S. I was able to remove Windows Indexer Filter's footprint, which was also constantly multiple CPU percentage points at last, by mostly removing the indexed places & file filters. But the excessive System's footprint described here remains.

Comment: Is it a new Windows installation?

Comment: @harrymc No, I have the installation probably since 1-2 years. (I have installed a new SSD a while ago. Components should be relatively standard.)

Answer (score 0):

General troubleshooting:

- Run `chkdsk` and also verify the SMART data of the disk
- Run the commands:

  `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
  ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html))
  `sfc /scannow`
  ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html))
- Run deep scans of the disk using multiple antivirus products.
  I suggest at least using Windows Defender,
  [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/)
  and one more from the list of
  [Best Free Antivirus Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-anti-virus-software.htm).
- If the problem continues do
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).